# Multiple suscribers to SSE being blocked via pubsub with Flask

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, publish-subscribe, server-sent-events

I'm creating a live data table page using Flask. The data shown is coming from a PostgreSQL database.

I am passing the new data being inserted into the database using the pubsub mechanism, and the operation is then transmitted using SSE to the front end Flask application.

Everything is working fine when I am opening one window but when I'm opening another window (to simulate multiple users), only the most recently loaded window receives the SSE. What am I doing wrong?

I tried multiple solutions, from using Flask in threaded mode to using gevent or gunicorn

Here is my code:

`main.py`

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
import psycopg2, pgpubsub
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
import time


app = Flask(__name__)

pubsub = pgpubsub.connect(database="postgres"....)


def get_connection():
    try:
        return psycopg2.connect(database="postgres.....")
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error connecting to DB: {e}"


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/events')
def events():
    def update_pusher():
        print('Started listening')
        pubsub.listen('data_changed')
        while True:
            for event in pubsub.events(yield_timeouts=True):
                if event is None:
                    pass
                else:
                    yield f"data: {event.payload}\nevent: online\n\n"
                    time.sleep(0.01)
    return Response(
        response=update_pusher(),
        mimetype='text/event-stream'
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
  http_server = WSGIServer(("localhost", 5003), app)
  http_server.serve_forever()
```

`index.html`

```
<p>This list is populated by server side events.</p>
<ul id="list"></ul>
<script>
    var eventSource = new EventSource("/events")
    eventSource.addEventListener("online", function(e) {
      // console.log(e.data.color)
      data = JSON.parse(e.data)
      const li = document.createElement('li')
      li.innerText = data
      list.appendChild(li)
    }, false)
```